# Getting invalid identifier error while converting varchar2 column to number datatyope

Tags: oracle, types, type-conversion, left-join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have A table with varchar2 column (That column contains multi values like space, numeric and alphanumeric). And B table with number column.
I need to join A table with B table using above columns.
I have used TO_NUMBER(A.Column) in join condition it is throwing error invalid identifier 'A.Column'. I have tried various way but still i am getting same error.

Example:

In select:
Case when regexp like (A.column,'[0-9]') then to_number(trim(A.column)) else null end as A

In join condition:
Left join B ON
B.column=to_number(A.column)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Oracle?

In 12.2 and later, you can add a `default null on conversion error` to your `to_number` call

```
          a
left join b 
       on b.column = to_number( a.column default null on conversion error )
```

In earlier versions, you'd need to join on the `case` statement or on a user-defined function call.  Something like

```
create or replace function safe_to_number( p_str in varchar2 )
  return number
is
  l_num number;
begin
  begin
    l_num := to_number( p_str );
  exception
    when others then
      l_num := null;
  end;

  return l_num;
end;

          a
left join b 
       on b.column = safe_to_number( a.column )
```

Assuming your `case` statement works (which implies that all your numbers are integers with no thousands separators)

```
          a
left join b 
       on b.column = Case when regexp_like (A.column,'[0-9]') 
                          then to_number(trim(A.column)) 
                          else null 
                      end
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Its working now